# ¿Como cambiar el formato a tiempo hh:mm:ss de una variable de instancia en Ruby on Rails?

Tags: json, api, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo un metodo que renderiza a json una consulta a la base de datos, pero requiero cambiar el formato de una columna a formato hh:mm:ss, el controlador es el siguiente:

```
class EficienciasController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @eficiencias = Eficiencia.select(:MOTIVO, :TIEMPO_MUERTO).where({FECHA: 
      @dia, MAQUINA: 'MINI LINE 618'}).order('ARRANQUE DESC').take(10) 
      //Aqui es donde supongo que se deberia de realizar el formateo para que Rails lo muestre en JSON :TIEMPO_MUERTO en formato hh:mm:ss
      render json: @eficiencias        
    end
end
```

¿Como puedo redormatear para que se muestre correctamente?

Comment: La respuesta de L. Ronquillo, si la aplicas correctamente, debería funcionar, pero no es para nada escalable. Si vas a usar extensivamente respuestas en json, te sugeriría evaluar el uso de gemas como [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder), [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) o [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) para ayudarte con templates a filtrar qué campos vas a necesitar o no en tu json, si quieres entregar elementos asociados a tu registro(s) retornado(s), además del formato de los atributos, entre eso, dar formato a las fechas.

Comment: @AlterLagos Tengo la gema active_model_serializers he leido la documentacion pero no encuentro como realizar la conversion de la columna a formato time desde allí ¿tienes alguna idea?

Comment: Si tienes una pregunta nueva, no edites la que ya hiciste, mejor haz una nueva.
Para quien llegue a ver tu pregunta, ve el título que no tiene ninguna relación con la pregunta, luego las respuestas tampoco. Además si realizas una nueva pregunta, es más probable que llegue gente a contestar en vez de revisar una que ya fue creada. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

puedes utlizar `strftime()` de la siguiente manera:

```
@eficiencias.TIEMPO_MUERTO=@eficiencias.TIEMPO_MUERTO.strftime("H%:M%:S%")
```

strftime se encarga de formatear fechas, H%, M% y S% están indicando qué se va a mostrar, lo demás tu lo puedes agregar a tu gusto, como en este caso fue ":" entre cada uno de los tres.
Si deseas ver más formatos de la función, consulta la [documentación del método](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

Comment: `@eficiencias` sería un objeto activerecord relation, así que tu respuesta no funcionaría tal cual la muestras. Deberías usar un map o algo para iterar el objeto